# Display (an updating) clock with UTC time and date

Tags: javascript, clock, utc

This code snippet works great for displaying the local time (updating every second) ie. a local clock.
I would like to modify it to display the UTC/GMT time in the same format. Any input would be most appreciated.

Local clock Javascript and HTML:

```js
function date_time(id) {
  date = new Date;
  year = date.getFullYear();
  month = date.getMonth();
  months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'Jully', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
  d = date.getDate();
  day = date.getDay();
  days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
  h = date.getHours();
  if (h < 10) {
    h = "0" + h;
  }
  m = date.getMinutes();
  if (m < 10) {
    m = "0" + m;
  }
  s = date.getSeconds();
  if (s < 10) {
    s = "0" + s;
  }
  result = '' + days[day] + ' ' + months[month] + ' ' + d + ' ' + year + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
  setTimeout('date_time("' + id + '");', '1000');
  return true;
}

window.onload = date_time('date_time');
```

```html
<div id="date_time"></div>
```

Comment: Your function does not return a function so you need `window.onload = function() { date_time('date_time'); }`

Comment: Also move the arrays outside the function. No need to create them every second

Comment: `function pad(num) { return ("0"+num).slice(-2) }`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `var` - otherwise you'll pollute the parent context with long-lived properties.
2. Use `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn )` instead of blindly overwriting the `onload` property.
3. Use the `UTC` functions on the `Date.prototype`:

   - `getFullYear()` should be `getUTCFullYear()`
   - `getMonth()` should be `getUTCMonth()`
   - `getDate()` should be `getUTCDate()`
   - and so on...
4. Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` to set an element's text as this avoids an expensive reparse.
5. You don't need to convert the function name to a string in `setTimeout`, just pass the function directly. If you need to supply arguments then use `Function.prototype.bind` to return a new `Function` object with presupplied arguments.
6. The `timeout` value should be a `number` literal, not a string.
7. Current Javascript programming conventions do not use `snake_case` for non-const identifiers, use `PascalCase` and `camelCase` instead.
8. You don't need intermediate variables for all of the date components.
9. As the month and day names are constant, they should be in a non-local (pseudo-`static`) variable.
10. Use a timeout of 500ms not 1000ms because it's the Nyquist-frequency of a clock at 1Hz and to reduce lag. I actually recommend using a timeout of 16ms to keep lag to a minimum (so it's updated every frame on a 60Hz display and to mitigate clock jitter in the browser's JavaScript scheduler).

Here's how I'd do it:

```
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", ... ];
var days   = [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday" ... ];

function updateClock( elementId ) {

    var dt = new Date();

    var h = dt.getUTCHours().toString();
    h = h.length == 1 ? '0' + h : h;

    var m = dt.getUTCMinutes().toString();
    m = m.length == 1 ? '0' + m : m;

    var s = dt.getUTCSeconds().toString();
    s = s.length == 1 ? '0' + s : s;

    var result = days[ dt.getUTCDaty ] + ' ' + months[ dt.getUTCMonth() ] + ' ' + dt.getUTCFullYear() + ' ' + h + ':' m + ':' + s;
    document.getElementById( elementId ).textContent = result;

    setTimeout( updateClock.bind( this, elementId ), 100 );
}

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(e) { updateClock('date_time'); } )
```